# Want to get result between time range in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, join

I have some records, i want to get records from them where item is not between given time range, here is my code that i already tried but no success

```
$other_hour_trade = DB::table('finaltrade')
        ->join('exchanges', 'finaltrade.exchange_id', '=', 'exchanges.id')
        ->select('finaltrade.*')
        ->where('finaltrade.user_id', $user_id)
        ->whereNotBetween('finaltrade.created_at', [DB::raw('exchanges.start_time'), DB::raw("ADDTIME(exchanges.start_time, '01:00:00')")])
        ->whereNotBetween('finaltrade.created_at', [DB::raw('exchanges.close_time'), DB::raw("SUBTIME(exchanges.close_time, '01:00:00')")])
        ->get();
```

'finaltrade.created_at' is a datetime field and 
'exchanges.start_time' and 'exchanges.close_time' is a only time field

I have join two tables to get results

Comment: What Laravel version are you using?

Comment: Laravel 5.3 version

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to make this work directly using `whereNotBetween`, but since you're already trying to resort to some raw SQL in your current code, why not just use `whereRaw` instead:

```
$other_hour_trade = DB::table('finaltrade')
    ->join('exchanges', 'finaltrade.exchange_id', '=', 'exchanges.id')
    ->select('finaltrade.*')
    ->where('finaltrade.user_id', $user_id)
    ->whereRaw("finaltrade.created_at NOT BETWEEN exchanges.start_time AND ADDTIME(exchanges.start_time, '01:00:00')")
    ->whereRaw("finaltrade.created_at NOT BETWEEN exchanges.close_time AND SUBTIME(exchanges.close_time, '01:00:00')")
    ->get();
```

Comment: @ColinBarstow If I told you that I don't know Eloquent would you believe me?  I just tried to fix the OP's Laravel code.

Comment: @Colin Barstow no idea about it

Comment: i think because 'finaltrade.created_at' is a datetime field and 'exchanges.start_time' and 'exchanges.close_time' is a only time field

Comment: we need to filter only time from finaltrade.created_at

Comment: I'm sorry I meant to post this on OP, that wasn't intended for you at all.

Comment: Did you try `time(finaltrade.created_at)`?